# Change the effect of jQuery repeater delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a jQuery repeater form and it works perfectly fine when I use it as it is but I want to tweak the delete button effect. It has "slideup" jQuery effect but I want to change it my own effect so I have tried few methods but I haven't able to delete the items in the form.

Below is my code and methods I have tried.

**form.html**

```
<form role="form" action="//" method="post" class="mt-repeater form-horizontal">
    <div data-repeater-list="group-a">
        <div class="mt-repeater-input">
            <label>Organization</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-repeater-input">
            <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-delete class="btn btn-danger mt-repeater-delete inp-del">
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-repeater-create class="btn btn-success mt-repeater-add uadd_btn">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="u-submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

**Actual form-repeater.min.js**

```
var FormRepeater=function(){return{init:function(){$(".mt-repeater").each(function(){$(this).repeater({show:function(){$(this).slideDown(),$(".date-picker").datepicker({rtl:App.isRTL(),orientation:"left",autoclose:!0})},hide:function(e){$(this.slideUp(e)},ready:function(e){}})})}}}();jQuery(document).ready(function(){FormRepeater.init()});
```

The above JS works fine because I haven't tweaked anything inside the JS code.  But in below code I tweaked as per my requirement as you can see I changed `$(this.slideUp(e)` to `$(this).css("background","red")`. So the effect works fine but it doesn't delete the item.  How can I achieve my requirements using below code?

**Tried form-repeater.min.js**

```
var FormRepeater=function(){return{init:function(){$(".mt-repeater").each(function(){$(this).repeater({show:function(){$(this).slideDown(),$(".date-picker").datepicker({rtl:App.isRTL(),orientation:"left",autoclose:!0})},hide:function(e){$(this).css("background","red")},ready:function(e){}})})}}}();jQuery(document).ready(function(){FormRepeater.init()});
```

Comment: Try making a class with that css for eg `.delete{background:red}` and then use jquery add class `$( this ).addClass( "delete" );` this should do what you want i belive

Comment: I got your point but if I don't use "slideUp()" or any sliding method of jquery then that item is not deleting. @rawk

Comment: my apologies i spaced.

Comment: Asking us to read and edit minified JS is pretty crazy - and surely is not making things easy for yourself either! The easier you make it for ppl to help you, the more likely you are to get help.  Edit your question, add readable JS.